# Is there a way to make sure to run lambda in sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking for a way to make my lambda to process events from a queue or event bus. But I need to ensure there is only one instance of lambda running. I need to set the concurrency limit to 1 to make sure there is no concurrency execution of the lambda.

If I use SQS or Event bus as the source of streaming to lambda, how can I ensure they don't trigger the lambda when it is running? otherwise my lambda will be easily throttled. Is there a way to control SQS to send event to lambda only when it is idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reserved Concurrency to effectively set a concurrency limit for your function - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html

The relevant excerpt is:

> To ensure that a function can always reach a certain level of
> concurrency, configure the function with reserved concurrency. When a
> function has reserved concurrency, no other function can use that
> concurrency. **Reserved concurrency also limits the maximum concurrency
> for the function, and applies to the function as a whole, including
> versions and aliases.**

Comment: How can I ensure my lambda is not throttled?

Comment: I thought what you were asking for is how to throttle it to one execution at a time? Have I not understood what you're looking for?

If you set Reserved Concurrency to 1, it will always have 1 execution available within your account and never more than that. The other functions in your account can then have up to 999 (1000 - 1) concurrent executions.

Comment: yes, you are right, this is what I am asking for

Comment: Then reserved concurrency is what you want. It will ensure that only 1 copy can run at a time.

Comment: yes, but it will throttle my lambda if there is another event sent from SQS or event bus right? Is there a way for me to control SQS to send event only when lambda is idle?

Comment: SQS is a queue - if the lambda is currently running then the next message will wait on the queue and be processed by a new invocation after the current process has run.